# Filter queryset for foreign key

Tags: django, filter

I need to filter the books associated with my serie model

My models.py

```
class Serie(models.Model):
    serie = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'serie', always_update = True)

class Book(models.Model):
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    serie_slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'serie', always_update = True, null = True)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'book_title', always_update = True, null = True)
    resume = RichTextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
```

My views.py

```
class index(ListView):
    model = Serie
    template_name = 'serie_book_list.html'
    ordering = ['id']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        search = self.request.GET.get('buscar', None)

        if search:
            context = context.filter(
                Q(serie__icontains = search) |
                Q(author__name__icontains = search) |
                Q(Book.objects.filter(book_title__icontains = search))
            )
        return context
```

I tried to use this code `Q(Book.objects.filter(book_title__icontains = search))`, but without success.

`Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your filter `Q(Book.objects.filter(book_title__icontains = search))` not match any field in `Serie`

try this:

```
context = context.filter(
            Q(serie__icontains=search) |
            Q(author__name__icontains=search) |
            Q(book__book_title__icontains=search))
        )
```

Comment: Works. search series, authors and now books. But now something strange happens. when I look for a series that has three books for example, it prints the same series three times

http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/?buscar=COMANDANTE+SERVAZ

http://prntscr.com/vv7t3w

Comment: you can try distinct() before return context

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: It's works, my friend. Thx  

`).distinct()`